# Results from $K$-theory which could be used to motivate an undergraduate to study it

Tags: topological-k-theory, k-theory

From the notes on $K$-theory from Allen Hatcher, one notices that $K$-theory was used to prove that the only division algebras over $\mathbb{R}$ are the real, complex, quaternion and octonion algebras with division.

Which other strong results from $K$-theory exist that are understandable for an undergraduate student to motivate him/her to study $K$-theory?

Comment: I wouldn't expect $K$-theory to be at the level of a typical undergraduate (or at least at the level of the typical undergraduate curriculum). The typical introduction to the subject is via characteristic classes of vector bundles over manifolds, and that requires a decent amount of algebraic topology, homological algebra, etc.

Comment: @anomaly: I interpreted the question as asking for examples of understandable results which were proved using $K$-theory.

Comment: But the point of my question is get results that undergraduate students can understand and could motivate them to study it (The K-theory)

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Right, but the motivating examples of classifying vector bundles, modules, sequences, etc. modulo trivial ones might be hard to explain at the undergrad level. Determining, for example, which spheres are parallelizable is not hard to explain (at least, presenting it as a question about vector fields in $\mathbb{R}^n$), though it may be hard to explain why the question is a hard one. Or not; I look forward to reading the answers here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Hairy Ball Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem) states that every vector field on $S^2$ has a zero, unlike the circle $S^1$ which has a nowhere-zero vector field, usually written $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}$. So a natural question to ask is which spheres $S^n$ have a nowhere-zero vector field? Given the observations so far, one might guess that it depends on the parity of $n$ (i.e. whether $n$ is even or odd). This turns out to be the case. It follows from the [Poincaré-Hopf Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem) that a closed manifold has a nowhere-zero vector field if and only if it has Euler characteristic zero. As $\chi(S^n) = 1 + (-1)^n$, we see that $S^n$ has a nowhere-zero vector field if and only if $n$ is odd.

Now that we know which spheres admit a nowhere-zero vector field, we can try to determine how many such vector fields they admit. Of course, we could just take the nowhere-zero vector field we have and multiply by a non-zero number to obtain another nowhere-zero vector field. To avoid this kind of redundancy, we instead ask a more refined question:

> What is the maximal number of linearly independent vector fields on $S^n$?

A collection of vector fields $V_1, \dots, V_k$ on a smooth manifold $M$ are said to be *linearly independent* if $\{V_1(x), \dots, V_k(x)\}$ is linearly independent for every $x$.

If $n$ is even, the answer is zero. If $n$ is odd, the answer is at least $1$, but is at most $n$. If the answer is $n$, then $S^n$ is said to be *parallelisable* (i.e. the tangent bundle is trivial). The only values of $n$ for which $S^n$ is parallelisable are $n = 0, 1, 3,$ and $7$ which is related to the fact that they are the unit spheres in $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{H}$, and $\mathbb{O}$ respectively. So for every other odd value of $n$, we know the answer is at least one but at most $n - 1$.

The highlighted problem was resolved by Frank Adams in his $1962$ paper *Vector Fields on Spheres*. It had been previously shown that there are at least $\rho(n+1) - 1$ linearly independent vector fields on $S^n$, and Adams showed that it it does not admit $\rho(n+1)$ linearly independent vector fields. Here $\rho(n)$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ Radon-Hurwitz number: write $n = 2^{4a+b}c$ with $a, b, c$ non-negative integers, $c$ odd, and $0 \leq b \leq 3$, then $\rho(n) = 2^b + 8a$. In his paper, Adams combines homotopy theory and topological $K$-theory in order to solve the aforementioned problem (which lies in the realm of differential topology).

I have listed some values below to give a sense of structure of these seemingly strange Radon-Hurwitz numbers.

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccccccccccc }
n & 1 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 9 & 11 & 13 & 15 & 17 & 19 & 21 & 23 & 25 & 27 & 29 & 31 & 33\\ 
\hline
\rho(n) & 1 & 3 & 1 & 7 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 8 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 7 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 9 & 1
\end{array}
$$

[Here](https://oeis.org/A053381/b053381.txt) is the first $10,000$ terms, just note that it is indexed differently: the left hand column is the value of $n$ and the right hand column is the value of $\rho(2n + 1)$. One can show that every integer $k \equiv 0, 1, 3, 7 \bmod 8$ is of the form $\rho(n)$ for some $n$. However, for a given $k$ the smallest $n$ for which $\rho(n) = k$ might be much larger than $k$. For example, in the first $10,000$ terms, the highest value of $\rho(n)$ is $27$.

Comment: Isn't this the section explained of the Adam operators of the Hatcher notes?

Comment: No. That section is discussing the solution of the problem you mention in your question (for which $n$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ a division algebra).

Comment: Now I see. I didn't read your post totally.